# How to add list together

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out a question and I'm getting confused. Basically I have a list and it's supposed to represent a bank statement. I'm trying to add the list together so the negative numbers, which is supposed to represent withdrawl, is added together and the positive numbers are added together to represent the deposits. So far I got

```
def statement(l):
    deposit = 0
    withdrawl = 0
    for a in l:
        a = sum(l)
    for b in l:
        if b == -b:
            b = sum(b)        
    return [a,-b]
```

but when I do `statement([30.95,-15.67,45.56,-55.00,43.78])` 
it returns `[49.620000000000005, -43.78]`
when it is supposed to return `[120.29,-70.67]` can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to do it:

```
In [1]: def statement(l):
   ...:     pos, neg = 0, 0
   ...:     for a in l:
   ...:         if a > 0: pos += a
   ...:         else: neg += a
   ...:     return pos, neg
   ...: 

In [2]: statement([30.95,-15.67,45.56,-55.00,43.78])
Out[2]: (120.29, -70.67)
```

It returns a `tuple` rather than a `list`, which seems more logical as the length is fixed.

---

Here's a couple of comments on your attempt:

```
for a in l:
    a = sum(l)
```

This will lead to the sum of all elements of `l` being calculated `len(l)` times, which doesn't make much sense. To get a sum, just do `a = sum(l)` once.

`if b == -b:` - you probably expect this to check if a number is negative, but in fact it checks if `b` equals zero, because zero is the only `x` so that `x == -x`. You want `if b < 0:`.

---

I checked which answer is faster on CPython 3.3, and unsurprisingly this one is about 2 times faster on the example given: `2.3 us per loop` vs `5.98 us per loop`.

Comment: This has the advantage that it only makes one pass through the sequence.  I timed this answer and the answer with two calls to `sum()` and this answer is faster.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to me now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I had some idea that in Cpython it might be faster to use the built-in looping in `sum()` twice if you were summing a list.  But then I realized it is trivial to measure instead of guessing, and I measured, and sure enough, this answer was faster in Cpython.  So I edited my comment and removed the part where I thought it might be faster in PyPy... it's just faster, period.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:

```
def statement(l):
    pos = sum(i for i in l if i > 0)
    neg = sum(i for i in l if i < 0)
    return pos, neg
```

Your mistake is that you try to assign to iteration variables. If you want to accumulate a value, define it as 0 first outside of the `for` loop then add on to that with each step.

At the end of the loop, `a` contains the sum of all the elements in `l`, and `b` contains the last element in `l`, because the final check always fails and `b` is never overwritten (which explains the result you got).

Comment: This is nice, but won't work with an iterator and is about 2 times slower than it could with a list :) Not an issue in this case probably.

Comment: also l should never be used as a parameter as it can be easily confused with 1.

Comment: @UdoKlein While I absolute do not agree with this style guide decision, I was using it regardless because it was that way in the question and I wanted to change as little as possible.